# MS Project Update Project and Level All

Tags: ms-project, scheduling, ms-project-2016

I have a bunch of tasks set up to get done by a dozen teams.  The teams are in as resources that have varying sizes.  200%, 400%, 600% whatever..

When I report the tasks, some have been started and are x% complete others have not been started.  I put in the priorities of the tasks, great so far.

Now I want to go to the Project and Update the project with the option of "Reschedule uncompleted work to start after today"  Great, Project does that.
Then when I click Level all, some of the tasks get scheduled to begin back at the beginning of the project in January.  Any idea how to stop that?

Comment: Never ever auto level.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to clear all leveling before implementing the Update Project dialog.   Tasks whose start dates are already beyond your "reschedule uncompleted work to start after:" date - including those delayed by leveling - will be ignored in the dialog.  When you re-run the leveler, the existing leveling delays will be removed, and there will be no logical constraints to keep the tasks in the future.